# Drop columns in Pandas dataframe based on row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to delete column(s) based on a value in the first row (0 or 1).

input is:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col A': [1, 1, 1], 'col B': [0, 1, 1], 'col C': [1, 1, 0], 'col D': [1, 0, 1], 'col E':  [0, 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

when value in first row is 0, then delete the columns (here for e.g.: B and E)
The drop of the column should happen by column indexes and not names.

expected output:

```
data = {'col A': [1, 1, 1],'col C': [1, 1, 0],'col D': [1, 0, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I was searching an answer already here but i did not find a satisfying solution for my problem:

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice the first row, identify the non-zeros values and select the columns to keep with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df.loc[:, df.loc[0].ne(0)]
```

*NB. This approach is fully independent of column names.*

Output:

```
   col A  col C  col D
0      1      1      1
1      1      1      0
2      1      0      1
```

Alternatively, using [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) (but this is less efficient **and won't work if you have duplicated column names**):

```
out = df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.loc[0].eq(0)])
```